# How to set height of SWT Tree?

Tags: java, tree, height, swt

Now the height of the tree depends on the number of elements of the first level. The tree is very large and watch it in a small frame, very uncomfortable.

[image: swt tree]
[image: swt tree full]

Comment: what layout are you using?

Comment: RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `RowLayout` you can use a `RowData` layout data object to specify the height of a row:

```java
RowData layoutData = new RowData(SWT.DEFAULT, height);

tree.setLayoutData(layoutData);
```